# Grails rest spring security plugin does not store generated token using GORM in database

Tags: rest, grails, spring-security

I am using the GORM option to store the generated token in database for my Grails 3.x application using grails spring security rest plugin.

The application generates the token but does not get stored in database. Do we need to override the tokenStorage method and have our own implementation to store the token in database

The plugin properties configured in application.groovy are listed below

```
     grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.validation.useBearerToken = false
        grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.endpointUrl = '/api/login'
        grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.validation.headerName = 'X-Auth-Token'
        grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.useJwt = false
        grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.useGorm=true
 grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.gorm.tokenDomainClassName='com.auth.AuthenticationToken'    
       grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.gorm.tokenValuePropertyName='token'
        grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.gorm.usernamePropertyName='username'
        grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.passwordPropertyName = 'password'
        grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.useJsonCredentials = true
        grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.useRequestParamsCredentials = false
        grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.rendering.authoritiesPropertyName = 'permissions'
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have added the following to your build.gradle:

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest:2.0.0.M2'  
compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest-gorm:2.0.0.M2'
```

And you have defined the following in application.groovy or application.yml

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.useGorm=true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.gorm.tokenDomainClassName = 'com.yourdomain.AuthenticationToken'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.gorm.tokenValuePropertyName = 'tokenValue'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.gorm.usernamePropertyName = 'username'
```

Comment: I was getting this error - "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/support/aware/GrailsApplicationAware".
but after adding 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest-gorm:2.0.0.M2' dependency, it is working fine now.

Comment: I am still facing one problem. If I make any request by sending valid token in the header, it works fine and when I use invalid token, it responds with status 401(unauthorized). But when I make the request without any header, it works fine (It should send status 401 instead).

Answer (score 1):

There is almost no information to help you. No build configuration, no logs, no idea how the requests are made...

But from the description of your problem, my guess is that you are missing the GORM module in your classpath. It's clearly stated [in the documentation](http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/latest/docs/index.html#configuration).

Be also sure to read the [what's new in 2.0](http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/latest/docs/index.html#_what_s_new_in_2_0) chapter.

Comment: I have to admit that I didn't read the documentation carefully until coming across this question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, token not stored and no error messages seen.

After installing the GORM plugin:

`compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest-gorm:2.0.0.M2"`

I could login and a token was saved into the table.